# Как в Ubuntu через терминал посмотреть список программ типа MC, которые установил конкретный пользователь?

Tags: linux, консоль

Нужен вывод программ именно по пользователю user1 в терминале.

Comment: Обычный пользователь не может «устанавливать» программы (если говорить про apt-get и т.д.), так что вопрос надо уточнить. Вот я user1. Как я поставил mc?

Comment: скачал архив с сайта, скомпилил и запустил:) тогда теоретически поможет find.

Comment: Ну я сам себе юзер который с помощью sudo apt install mc установил mc. Потом запустил sudo dpkg --get-selections и увидел кучу всего установленного вместе с системой. А мне надо только то, что установил я.

Comment: если Вы можете сделать sudo, то Вы уже не просто "юзер". sudo -это "super user do" - то есть, действия от имени суперпользователя.

Comment: Если sudo, значит установили уже не вы, а root. Список вручную установленных пакетов можно посмотреть с помощью `apt list --manual-installed` но скорее всего там тоже куча системного будет

Comment: Можно посмотреть логи /var/log/apt и сопоставить их с логами sudo где-то в /var/log/auth